# How do I make buttons work on Mobile phones?

Tags: html, vue.js, button, mobile, touch-event

I'm building a web app with Vue.js and I have a deployed version on Heroku. My client started testing the app through the Heroku version and discovered that the buttons on his mobile phone don't work. So far I've read that the issue can be buttons not working the same way on mobile and a few suggestions on using the 'touchstart' and 'touchend' events. Since I'm using vues directive syntax, I'm not sure if by using @touchstart or @touchend I'm doing something wrong. In this example, I'm using the normal @click syntax.

P.S. I only tested on iPhone devices.

```
<button
class="button"
type="button"
@click="logIn">
Log In
</button>
```

Comment: A standard `<button>` click event will definitely work on mobile, there's no need to use touch events. We need more details.

Comment: @DecadeMoon What else could help you figure this out? I only have an image of how the button looks on my phone but I can't share that with you here. The button styling on the phone is different from the desktop version. It's just text with a border around it.